# msfconsole and using bash variables

Tags: metasploit, bash

When trying to set `RHOSTS` for an auxiliary module, I tried using `$server`, which is a bash variable I've set before entering msfconsole. It is not readable from within msfconsole.

How do I access bash variables from msfconsole?

Comment: I think you can just pass bash variables via args by using -x option. This could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that metasploit do not contain all bash functionality. It has some basic commands like ls or ping but I am not sure if you can use full bash inside. You can try to create a script of echoing the variable and simple copy paste can do the job.